# jQuery "click" on textbox. How to add tab key support?

Tags: jquery

```
$("#textbox").one("click", function () {

});
```

How would I add support for the tab key? If the user on the previous textbox and then clicks the tab key and ends up on #textbox, that's when the function should be ran, as well as when the user decides to click instead of using the tab key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind to the `focus` event instead of the `click` event:

```
$("#textbox").one("focus", function () {
    //Do stuff
});
```

[From MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL_Tutorial/Focus_and_Selection):

> The focus event is used to respond when the focus is given to an
>   element.

and

> The user can change the focus by clicking an element with the mouse or
>   by pressing the TAB key. When the TAB key is pressed, the next element
>   is given the focus. To step backwards, the Shift key and Tab key can
>   be pressed.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `focus` event:

```
$("#textbox").one("focus", function () {
    // Fires when the textbox gets focus, whether via the
    // mouse or the keyboard (e.g., tab)
});
```

Are you sure you only want it to be called the *first* time the control is focussed? (You've used [`one`](http://api.jquery.com/one).) Not subsequent times? If you want it to happen every time, use [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on) rather than `one`.

Comment: Yes, just the first time, since it's for autocomplete (it pulls all the names only once).

Answer (score 1):

You can use `focus` event, it supports both `tab` and `click` events:

```
$("#textbox").one("focus", function () {

});
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll do something.. determined by the key code?

```
$("#textbox").one("keydown",function(ev){
  var c=ev.KeyCode||ev.which;
  if(c==9){
    ev.preventDefault();
    //something...
  }
});
```